# Adding objects to the DOM after adding new data to the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array of objects which i populate on a button click.

When populating this array i make sure that i only add 10 objects to it. 
When this is all loaded in the dom i give the user the oppertunity to add a few more objects.

I do this like this:

```
$scope.Information = [];

 $.each(data, function (i, v) {

    if (i<= 9)
     $scope.Information.push(data[i]);

     if(i >= 10) {
         cookieList.push(data[i]);
      }

}

 if (cookieList.length) {
     localStorage.setItem("toDoList", JSON.stringify(cookieList));
     $(".showMore").removeClass("hidden");
  }

    $(".showMore").on("click", function() {
        var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toDoList"));
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(obj.length);
        SetSpinner('show');
        $scope.Information.push(obj);
        SetSpinner('hide');
        //$.removeCookie("toDoList2");
    });
```

part of the HTML:

```
       <div ng-repeat="info in Information" class="apartment container" style="padding-right:35px !important">

              <div class="row" style="height:100%">
                   <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12">
                       <div>
                           <h4 class="toDoListHeadings">Nummer</h4>
                           <div style="margin-top: -15px; width:100%">
                               <span class="toDoListItems number">
                                    {{info.orderraderid}}
                                </span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
       </div>
```

My issue: When i add objects to my array of objects "$scope.Information.push(obj);" I assumed that they would get added in the DOM but they do not, how do i do this the angular way?

EDIT MY SOLOUTION:

edited the HTML to use ng-click and the method is as follows:

```
$scope.addMore = function() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toDoList"));
    SetSpinner('show');

    $.each(obj, function(i,v) {
        $scope.Information.push(v);
    });

    SetSpinner('hide');
}
```

Comment: I am using ng-repeat, look at my html. Am i missing something?

Comment: yes i am sure im running it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the angular way:

### The view

```
<!-- Reference your `myapp` module -->
<body data-ng-app="myapp">
  
  <!-- Reference `InfoController` to control this DOM element and its children -->
  <section data-ng-controller="InfoController">

    <!-- Use `ng-click` directive to call the `$scope.showMore` method binded from the controller -->
    <!-- Use `ng-show` directive to show the button if `$scope.showMoreButton` is true, else hide it -->
    <button data-ng-click="showMore()" data-ng-show="showMoreButton">
      Show more
    </button>
    
    <div ng-repeat="info in Information" class="apartment container" style="padding-right:35px !important">
      <div class="row" style="height:100%">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12">
          <div>
            <h4 class="toDoListHeadings">Nummer</h4>
            <div style="margin-top: -15px; width:100%">
              <span class="toDoListItems number">
                {{info.orderraderid}}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  
</body>
```

### The module and controller

```
// defining angular application main module
var app = angular.module('myapp',[])  

// defining a controller in this module
// injecting $scope service to the controller for data binding with the html view 
// (in the DOM element surrounded by ng-controller directive)
app.controller('InfoController',function($scope){
  
  $scope.Information = [];
  $scope.showMoreButton = false; 
  // Bind controller method to the $scope instead of $(".showMore").on("click", function() {});
  $scope.showMore = function(){
      var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toDoList"));
      console.log(obj);
      console.log(obj.length);
      SetSpinner('show');
      $scope.Information.push(obj);
      SetSpinner('hide');
      //$.removeCookie("toDoList2");    
  };
  
  
  $.each(data, function (i, v) {
    if (i<= 9) $scope.Information.push(data[i]);
    if(i >= 10) cookieList.push(data[i]);
  });
  
  if (cookieList.length) {
    localStorage.setItem("toDoList", JSON.stringify(cookieList));
    
    //$(".showMore").removeClass("hidden");
    $scope.showMoreButton = true; // use $scope vars and ng-class directive instead of $(".xyz").blahBlah()
  }
});
```

Comment: You could even replace this $.each by a angular.forEach

Comment: Yes but its not required. Its just a `for i in a` wrapper so ... why not.

Comment: My question was a bit vague but you and ThibaudL answer put me on the right track. You were both correct, I should not use jquery as a click handler and should use ng-click but i guess that old habbits die hard. @ThibaudL I want you to know that i am accepting this answer because of the broader details which i found more helpful but both of you were correct. Thank you for the help!

You are most welcomed to look under edits and see how i solved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right about habits. While coding angular apps, think about in angular, each piece of code has its own correct place in one of the possible angular module sub-element: controller, service, filter or directive. Also you can create sub-modules for deeper modularization. Secondly, you can use jquery, but don't use jQuery selectors  $('.abc') or else. Instead, you need a directive.

Comment: You'r welcome and there is no probleme, Rémi Bechera's answer was really well detailled, but I feel obliged to insist about the $.each as you both said habits die hard that's the reason of the 'why not'. I always try to do a code without using JQuery

Comment: @ThibaudL Yes you're right about that, I agree. I didn't replace it in code just because it is not critical for the angular way. Its recommended, but using it is without consequence. I voluntary  wanted to distinguish these two kind of jquery use case. But fundamentally, I agree. In fact, I never use it in my devs.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN A complementary note about jQuery and Angular: take a look at [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), the bundled jqlite by angular

Answer (score 4):

You should not use JQuery, use ng-click to detect the click, because angular has no idea when JQuery is done and when it needs to refresh the interface

Comment: If you really really really want to use JQuery then you need to do a $scope.$apply() to refresh your interface

Comment: Ive tried not using jquery as a click handler and also used $apply(). The thing that happens is that the objects i want to add in the DOM get added to the last object of the array instead of getting added to the array itself.

Comment: I can see no reason for it to be added to the last item, can you make a code snippet or fiddle / plunkr reproducing your issue maybe ?? Otherwise at least the output